# How can I combine two event functions of properties such as JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var question = document.querySelector('.p1')
var result = document.querySelector('.p2')

button.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    question.innerHTML = input.value;
    input.value = "";
    input.placeholder = question.textContent[question.textContent.length-1]+ " finished word?";
    input.focus();
})
/*
button.addEventListener("click",function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault;
    if(question.textContent[question.textContent.length-1] === input.value[0])
    {
        question.innerHTML = input.value;
        input.value = "";
        result.innerHTML = "good"
        input.focus();
    }
    else{
        input.value = "";
        result.innerHTML = "bad"
        input.focus();
    }
})
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="p1"></p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="input first word">
    <button type="button">submit</button>
    <p class="p2"></p>
    <script src="끝말잇기2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sorry that I asked you a question using a translator because I can't speak English.

I have a question in the JavaScript code.

First, the first function is input the first word, and the event is click.

The second function is the same as the first letter of the word you received, and the last letter is the same, so you put the first letter in the first letter.

These two functions can be combined, but I think both functions are duplicated because they are event clicks.

How can i write code that combines two functions and performs sequential functions?

Comment: Write a third function and call both former function sequentially in this new third function. That third function you use as actual event listener.

Comment: feel free to check, both event listeners are used and they work smoothly together :D

Answer (score 0):

#### One Function Solution

There is no need for two functions, you can write it as one function. Consider here that you don't reset the *input.value* twice when you combine both. Just reset it at the end of the function.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var question = document.querySelector('.p1')
var result = document.querySelector('.p2')

button.addEventListener("click", function() {

  question.innerHTML = input.value;
  input.placeholder = question.textContent[question.textContent.length - 1] + " finished word?";
  input.focus();

  if (question.textContent[question.textContent.length - 1] === input.value[0]) {
    question.innerHTML = input.value;
    input.value = "";
    result.innerHTML = "good"
    input.focus();
  } else {
    input.value = "";
    result.innerHTML = "bad"
    input.focus();
  }
})
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="p1"></p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="input first word">
  <button type="button">submit</button>
  <p class="p2"></p>
  <script src="끝말잇기2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Call Consecutively Wrapper Function

If you want to use two functions you can do a *wrapper function* and inside it you can call your two other functions.

Then when the button get's pressed you call the *wrapper function* which will proceed the two other functions consecutively.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var question = document.querySelector('.p1')
var result = document.querySelector('.p2')




button.addEventListener("click", wrapperFunction);

function a() {
  question.innerHTML = input.value;
  input.placeholder = question.textContent[question.textContent.length - 1] + " finished word?";
  input.focus();
}

function b() {
  if (question.textContent[question.textContent.length - 1] === input.value[0]) {
    question.innerHTML = input.value;
    input.value = "";
    result.innerHTML = "good"
    input.focus();
  } else {
    input.value = "";
    result.innerHTML = "bad"
    input.focus();
  }
}

function wrapperFunction() {
  a();
  b();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="p1"></p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="input first word">
  <button type="button">submit</button>
  <p class="p2"></p>
  <script src="끝말잇기2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `preventDefault`, then I added a `setTimeout` to changing `input.value` so both functions can run(with the input.value resource shared)

Because `setTimeout` is `asynchronous`, it would work well in situations like this, since it would wait until the other things finish running(I'm paraphrasing so don't quote me) then it will run.. making both functions work at the "same time"

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var question = document.querySelector('.p1')
var result = document.querySelector('.p2')


button.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    //e.preventDefault;
    question.innerHTML = input.value;
    setTimeout(()=>{input.value = "";},0)
    input.placeholder = question.textContent[question.textContent.length-1]+ " finished word?";
    input.focus();
})

button.addEventListener("click",function(ev){
    //ev.preventDefault;
    if(question.textContent[question.textContent.length-1] === input.value[0])
    {
        question.innerHTML = input.value;
        setTimeout(()=>{input.value = "";},0)
        result.innerHTML = "good"
        input.focus();
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(()=>{input.value = "";},0)
        result.innerHTML = "bad"
        input.focus();
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="p1"></p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="input first word">
    <button type="button">submit</button>
    <p class="p2"></p>
    <script src="끝말잇기2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```